# How to solve Cannot use import statement outside a module when running cdk deploy

Tags: javascript, typescript, aws-cdk

[image]

I have a project that is a typescript/js blend. It is structured as seen above. As you can see the bin contains a file that creates the cdk stack. The lib folder contains a file with all of my cdk code, which creates all of the AWS resources. However, this folder also contains a lot of js files, which also use react. Here is my issue when trying to run `cdk deploy` I get the error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` and yes, I have read every single post around this error, and it isn't as simple is adding `"type": "module"` to my ts config file. (I have tried this and get the error `TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for .../bin/aws-cdk-namespace-deployment.ts` The file that it yells at me about is in the bin folder. It's a typescript file, which definitely should use imports. Here is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "downlevelIteration": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "aws-cdk-namespace-deployment",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "bin": {
    "aws-cdk-namespace-deployment": "bin/aws-cdk-namespace-deployment.ts"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "test": "jest",
    "cdk": "cdk"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/register": "^7.18.9",
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.102",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "10.17.27",
    "@types/prettier": "2.6.0",
    "aws-cdk": "^2.39.1",
    "aws-cdk-lib": "^2.50.0",
    "aws-cdk-webpack-lambda-function": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.7",
    "babel-preset-airbnb": "^5.0.0",
    "better-sqlite3": "^7.6.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "knex": "^2.3.0",
    "mock-aws-s3": "^4.0.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "nock": "^13.2.9",
    "oracledb": "^5.5.0",
    "pg": "^8.8.0",
    "pg-native": "^3.0.1",
    "pg-query-stream": "^4.2.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "sqlite3": "^5.1.2",
    "tedious": "^15.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.4",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.163.0",
    "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.204.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1209.0",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "constructs": "^10.0.0",
    "d3": "^7.6.1",
    "esbuild": "^0.15.12",
    "joi": "^17.6.2",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "proptypes": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom-server": "^0.0.1",
    "s3-zip": "^3.2.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "winston": "^3.8.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "babel-plugin-styled-components",
      "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
    ]
  }
}
```

Again with the application structured as seen above and with tsconfig and package.json as seen above, when I run `npm run build && cdk deploy` I get the error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` any help of suggestions would be super appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle TS files in the process. Here's how I do mine using `tsx`:

```
node ./node_modules/.bin/cdk --app='tsx ./src/cdk/myCDKStacks.ts'
```

You could make a `bin` file if desired - I just pass my stack file directly as in above. `myCDKStack.ts` contains the code for all my stacks.